# Querying data in a hive partition with size greater than 0b

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, hdfs

I am using `hive` to query data partitioned as `instance/year/month/day` which resides in `s3`.

for a given partition for ex `instance='new'/year=2017/month=5/day=1` there exists several files compressed as .tsv.gz. Some of these files are maybe corrupt or have `0 B` at any given point of time.

When I querying the table built on top of it, I get the following error,

> `Unexpected end of input stream error.Vertex failed`

Is there a way to just query the files that have a size greater than 0 or not corrupted through hive?

Thanks.
JayZee